# Finalizar video de youtube embedado em as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Estou usando um video do youtube embedado em um flash. Quando o video termina, fica com a tela padrão do youtube de final de video, e sugere videos para o usuário.

Existe um modo de definir para o video pausar no seu frame final ou ir para outro frame assim que o video terminar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é não exibir os vídeos relacionados no final do vídeo, basta acrescentar o parametro **rel=0** no final da url.

Por exemplo:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/89Oc1UE7SS4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Mais informações:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=pt-br

> **rel** players compatíveis:  HTML5, AS3 /  0 ou 1. O valor padrão é 1. Este parâmetro indica se o player deve exibir vídeos
>   relacionados quando a reprodução do vídeo inicial acaba.

Comment: Opa funcionou bem, agradeço. Li essa documentação e pelo visto pulei o a parte sobre o rel.